# Invoking a function from within avy

Tags: avy

I have bound `avy-goto-char-timer` to `C-j` globally. But I want the key chord `C-j C-s` to invoke `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`. Is that possible ?

Comment: You want `C-j C-s` to invoke the function in what context? Everywhere or within a particular major mode (e.g. for some language mode)? If you want to do both of the above in the *same* keymap, that's not possible. For different keymaps, you will have to make `C-j` a prefix key in the keymap that corresponds to the context where you want `C-j C-s` to invoke `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`, which will override the global setting in that context (so you won't be able to use it to call `avy-goto-char-timer` in that context).

Comment: ok thanks for your answer